# How to fix Page Insights leverage caching using Google Cloud, Docker, Nginx and Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, docker, nginx

I host my website on **Google Cloud App Engine**, using **Docker**, **Nginx** web sever and **Laravel 5.4**.

After inspecting my website on **Google Page Insights** I get few warnings and I know how to fix them all except one - **Leverage Browser Caching**.

I tried to modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-app.conf with adding

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
  expires 365d;
}
location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
  expires 365d;
}
```

.. and restarting container. But this did not fix the situation.

Maybe someone can help me? Thank you.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
daemon off;
env DOCUMENT_ROOT;
env FRONT_CONTROLLER_FILE;
user  www-data;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log /dev/stderr info;
events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    include       gzip_params;
    server_tokens off;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    client_max_body_size 32m;

    access_log  /dev/stdout;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  650;
    keepalive_requests 10000;

    map $http_x_forwarded_proto $fastcgi_https {
        default '';
        https on;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-http.conf;

    upstream php-fpm {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=3s;
    }

    server {

        set_by_lua $docroot 'return os.getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT")';
        set_by_lua $front_controller_file 'return os.getenv("FRONT_CONTROLLER_FILE")';

        listen       8080;
        root $docroot;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
          expires 7d;
          access_log off;
          etag on;
          add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # CSS and Javascript
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
          expires 7d;
          access_log off;
          etag on;
          add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
          fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
          fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
          fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
          fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 4064k;
          fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        }

        # This default behavior is intentionally using regex to allow
        # users to override this with the exact match directive as follows:
        # location = /_ah/health {
        #   # Define your own behavior.
        # }
        #
        location ~ ^/_ah/health$ {
           access_log off;
           return 200 'ok';
        }

        # Allow users to specify their own configuration
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-app.conf;

        # Drop accesses for some files
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
        location ~ ~$           { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-app.conf

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
  expires 365d;
}
location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
  expires 365d;
}
location / {
  # try to serve files directly, fallback to the front controller
  try_files $uri /$front_controller_file$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Give your full `nginx config` if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite NGINX config by creating nginx.conf in your application root directory.